# Creating a new spreadsheet from a template

Tags: excel, vba

I am developing code which creates a copy of a template spreadsheet whenever text is input into any row within column A. The spreadsheet needs to be named after the text entered.

Currently I have the following code, the problem is that it does not name the new spreadsheet after the text I enter.

The code is as below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then
        Set wsNew = Sheets(Target.Text)
        If wsNew Is Nothing Then 
            Worksheets("Template").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
        'name new sheet code here

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you define and/or give value to `strWsName`?

Comment: That line of code is wrong and should be removed, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Did you mean to set new worksheet name to `Target.Text`?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then
        Set wsNew = Sheets(Target.Text)
        If wsNew Is Nothing Then 
            Worksheets("Template").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
        'name new sheet
        Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = Target.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit:

User could empty the cell in `A1:A10` which will create new tab called "**Template (2)**". You should also do check:

```
If Len(Target.Cells.Text) = 0 Then Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this to create the sheet based on the template with the desired name - but after testing and cleansing the proposed sheet name first for invalid characters

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim strSht As String

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wsNew = Sheets(Target.Text)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If wsNew Is Nothing Then
        If ValidSheetName(Target.Value) Then
        strSht = Target.Value
        Else
        strSht = CleanSheetName(Target.Value)
        End If
        End If
        Worksheets("Template").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = strSht
    End If
End Sub
```

**string cleaning code 1**

```
Function ValidSheetName(strIn As String) As Boolean
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    objRegex.Pattern = "[\<\>\*\\\/\?|]"
    ValidSheetName = Not objRegex.test(strIn)
End Function
```

**string cleaning code 2**

```
Function CleanSheetName(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[\<\>\*\\\/\?|]"
        CleanSheetName = .Replace(strIn, "_")
    End With
End Function
```